# Why won't my Gutenberg Instagram embed block work on front end when it works in the editor?

Tags: wordpress, instagram, oembed, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm embedding Instagram posts into the Wordpress Gutenberg editor using the Instagram block. Works fine in the editor, and the post embeds without any issues.

[image: Back-end, all good!]

On the front end, however, the Instagram link just sits there as text with no sign of any attempt to embed.

[image: Front-end, not so good]

A bit of digging led me to [this article](https://stallion-theme.co.uk/understanding-wordpress-oembed-and-unknown-postmeta-entries/) about `{{unknown}}` oEmbed cache entries in the database, which are present in my oEmbed database cache for the Instagram embeds that aren't working. However, I still can't figure out a solution, or a reason that this is happening.

There doesn't seem to be any issues with YouTube or Vimeo embeds on the site, it's only the Instagram one that's having problems. Again, the embed works absolutely fine in the back-end editor...

Has anyone else stumbled upon this odd front-end behaviour?

Comment: Still struggling with this. I've noticed that activating the default TwentyNineteen theme fixes the issue, so I know that it's my theme that's causing the problem. It's a modified version of the Plate starter theme (https://github.com/joshuaiz/plate) but I can't find anything in `functions.php` that's causing the issue. Stumped!

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: @F.A Yes, I've just added an answer to this. Hope it fixes your issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to this thanks to **@joshuaiz** following this up in a separate thread:

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/14351

Removing `$content_width = '100%';` from my theme's `functions.php` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

We are also experiencing this issue on our site. I noticed that `<script async src="//www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>` is being stripped out somewhere which is causing the embed not to load properly on the frontend. Allowing `script` tags fixes the issue by allowing the embed script to load, but introduces a security vulnerability, so we still haven't found a great workaround solution yet.

Edit: We decided to add `<script async src="//www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>` to the head tag. Still not ideal as it's loading on all pages, but a workaround for the time being that allows the instagram embed to load properly.

Comment: In my case adding <script async src="//www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script> to head did not solve the problem.     But I did see that it is stripped from the code.